# Alterar Destino de um Arquivo Atalho com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou mudando o nome de várias planilhas ao mesmo tempo, porem algumas delas tem atalhos, e em meio a mudança quero que os atalhos acompanhem essa mudança.

```
Sub changeTargetPath()

    Set wsc = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set Lnk = wsc.CreateShortcut(wsc.SpecialFolders("desktop") & "\tabela 1.lnk")

    Lnk.targetpath = """C:\Users\leandro.moreira\Desktop\tabela 1.xlsx"" C:\Users\leandro.moreira\Desktop\atalho 2.xlsx"
    Lnk.Description = "tabela 1"
    Lnk.Arguments = "C:\Users\leandro.moreira\Desktop\atalho 2.xlsx"
    Lnk.Save

End Sub
```

O que eu fiz de código é isso.

Comment: Olá, amigo! Vc sabe onde se encontram os atalhos que vc gostaria de atualizar? Se sim, fica mais fácil te ajudar. Digo isso pois não há uma maneira rápida de encontrar todos os atalhos linkados à um determinado arquivo no sistema.

Comment: Sei encontrar sim. O problema é trocar mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achei a resposta:

OBS: É necessário ativar a Referência: **Microsoft Shell Constrols And Automation**

```
Public Sub Change_Shortcut()

    Dim shell As Shell32.shell
    Dim folder As Shell32.folder
    Dim folderItem As Shell32.folderItem
    Dim shortcut As Shell32.ShellLinkObject

    Set shell = New Shell32.shell

    Set folder = shell.Namespace("C:\endereço/do/desktop")  'Só a pasta, não o arquivo
    If Not folder Is Nothing Then
        Set folderItem = folder.ParseName("C:\pasta\do\atalho\atalho.lnk")   'Endereço do atalho
        If Not folderItem Is Nothing Then
            Set shortcut = folderItem.GetLink
            If Not shortcut Is Nothing Then
                shortcut.Path = "C:\destino\do\atalho"    'mude o destino do atalho
                shortcut.Save
                MsgBox "Shortcut changed"
            Else
                MsgBox "Shortcut link within file not found"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Shortcut file not found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Desktop folder not found"
    End If

End Sub
```

Espero ter ajudado.